# Make ubuntu use specific part of screen only [Ubuntu 19.04]

Tags: screen, monitor, 19.04

I'm using pc and the screen is connected with vga cable . my screen is damaged like I only have some small part of it working in the center (damaged upper and bottom ) . so I want to make ubuntu only uses this specific part.
I searched for solutions but all was futile ,
also my graphic card is  AMD so I can't really use nvidia experience .
I even tried to change the settings of the monitor it self but there were very small range that I can change it and didn't help at all . any idea ?

Comment: The likelihood of this being achieved is slim. The amount of time required to make it work would be more than the cost of purchasing a new display. Unless you don't value your time in the slightest.

Comment: Going back to simple X and at terminal providing co-ords for top left, bottom right of windows would work, but would be a huge step back in time. It can be controlled by terminal, so you could start the editing of configs from another box which has a working screen until it's good enough that it opens in the part of the screen that works, but it'd be a mostly terminal driven process as it's not really built into most menu driven desktops.

Comment: Take a look at [ubuntu split ultrawide monitor](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ubuntu+split+ultrawide+monitor). It deals with creating two displays on a single monitor. This may be of use in your situation if you can disable or just ignore the broken region. It also may not work for all applications though as their  implementations can fairly heterogeneous.

Comment: Simplexion  : I'm broke.
guiverc : will try that and see what could I do , hope it works. 
SHawarden : well I already read all of them.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127911/due-to-a-broken-monitor-i-need-to-setup-only-the-right-half-of-my-screen

Answer (score 0):

You could turn down the resolution and then set the zoom or aspect setting on the screen so that it doesn't stretch the smaller, non native resolution.

Comment: I feel this might work , but could you illustrate more , Like the zoom or aspect settings is on the actual monitor settings or it's on ubuntu screen settings ?
If you could tell me steps that would be awesome also

Comment: Monitor settings. Most televisions and monitors have a setting usually labeled "zoom" or "aspect". It's intended to help you stretch odd sized input images. A side effect is that if you cycle through the presets you'll probably find one that displays the output in its original size, so if you have a 1920x1080 monitor and you set your output resolution to something like 1600x900, you'll have a black border. There's also a setting in Ubuntu I've seen labeled "Adjust for TV" that's intended to compensate for overscan by adding an inch or so border around your image without hurting resolution.

Answer (score 0):

This is **just a workaround** since the maximized windows will still fill more than the chosen screen. Yet, this makes it possible to see most of the window frames so that you can manually resize them to the right part of the screen.

---

I had broken the roughly right half of the screen of a small 11.2 inch netbook. Therefore I changed the resolution and other parameters of the comment of the [user above](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/88401/binaryfrost) at [Use partial screen display](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665118/442338) until the screen display ended exactly at the break line.

```
xrandr --current  --output eDP-1 --fb 960x1100 --transform 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

If you want this to be on the right side, instead, you need to shift it to the right

```
xrandr --current  --output eDP-1 --fb 960x1100 --transform 1,0,-840,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

This is just the result of checks, the break is 840 pixels to the right in my case. In your case, you need to change the parameter that shifts the screen from top to bottom or that shrinks it vertically, see the [docs of xrandr](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr):

> If underscan is not available another solution is using xrandr
> --transform a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i, which applies a transformation matrix on the output. See the xrandr(1) § RandR_version_1.3_options manual
> page for the explanation of the transformation.
>
> For example, the transformation scaling horizontal coordinates by 0.8,
> vertical coordinates by 1.04 and moving the screen by 35 pixels right
> and 19 pixels down, is:
>
> ```
> $ xrandr --output HDMI1 --transform 0.80,0,-35,0,1.04,-19,0,0,1
> ```

(you need to change HDMI1 to eDP-1 if you want the change on the "home screen")

Some additional tricks:

- At best you have the chance to connect a second monitor in mirrored mode so that you can always get back to see the uncut terminal window.
- You can also just use the "Arrow-up button" twice + "Enter button" to get back to the previous state.
- Do not connect the mirrored second screen during the final checks since in my case, there was a shift to the right that disappeared as soon as I took off the second monitor.
- If for some reasons, you want the screen to be skewed or turned, check the other parameters.

You must check the final results on the broken screen only. Strangely, after having found a way to show the screen directly on the left, bordering at the rough middle of the screen, you still do not see the most right side of any maximized window. Instead, you will still have to narrow down the windows so that you can see them as a whole in the right screen space. That might get solved using a display manager, see [xrandr: display borders are cutoff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387675/xrandr-display-borders-are-cutoff?rq=1), but I have not spent time on this.

Strangly, after some successful tests, the results fell back to always just show just the message:

```
xrandr: specified screen 960x1100 not large enough for output eDP-1 (1920x1080+1+680+1)
xrandr: specified screen 960x1100 not large enough for output HDMI-1 (1680x1050+0+0)
```

But it worked at the start of the tests, thus it also might work for you.

To get further with this, find out about possible resolution and display names with:

```
$ xrandr -q
```